# learning prefix sum by tree reduction

Tags: parallel-processing, tree, mpi, prefix-sum

I need to learn about prefix sum by tree reduction and write an MPI code in C for that. I already know prefix sum by recursive doubling or scan, and have some background in programming by MPI. Here is the structure of tree reduction which I should learn about:

[image: tree reduction]

Anyone can suggest some nice materials for learning prefix sum by tree reduction or explain it here? I googled it but couldn't find a good note with clear explanation!

Comment: Actually I can't understand this figure. On Gpu you can perform the parallel scan by build a balanced binary tree on the input data and sweep it to and from the root to compute the prefix sum: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs570/hw/parprefix.pdf